Getting proper crop coordinates of a snip
I am building a chrome extension for OCR. Users can upload pdf and it gets converted into an image and I render it in a new tab. I create a overlay on top of the image container and let the user take a snippet and store the crop coordinates. The issue is that the crop is not happening with respect to the overlay I created over the image container but rather its happening with respect to the entire screen.
function createSelection() {
    if (selection && selection.parentNode) {
        selection.parentNode.removeChild(selection);
    }
    
    selection = document.createElement("div");
    selection.style.border = "2px solid #8e4dff";
    selection.style.position = "fixed";
    selection.style.zIndex = "900"; // above the overlay
    selection.style.display = "none";
    selection.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(selection);   
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request.action)
    if (request.action === "showImageForSelection") {
        dataUrl = request.dataUrl;
        createOverlay();
        createSelection();
        
        overlay.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            isDragging = true;
            console.log("START DRAGG")
            // Mouse position relative to the image
            const containerRect = overlay.getBoundingClientRect();
            startX = e.clientX - containerRect.left;
            startY = e.clientY - containerRect.top;

            selection.style.left = `${startX + containerRect.left}px`;
            selection.style.top = `${startY + containerRect.top}px`;
            selection.style.width = "0px";
            selection.style.height = "0px";
            selection.style.display = "block";
        });
        overlay.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            if (!isDragging) return;
            const containerRect = overlay.getBoundingClientRect();
            const currentX = e.clientX - containerRect.left;
            const currentY = e.clientY - containerRect.top;

            const width = currentX - startX;
            const height = currentY - startY;

            selection.style.width = `${Math.abs(width)}px`;
            selection.style.height = `${Math.abs(height)}px`;

            if (width < 0) {
                selection.style.left = `${startX + width + containerRect.left}px`;
            } else {
                selection.style.left = `${startX + containerRect.left}px`;
            }

            if (height < 0) {
                selection.style.top = `${startY + height + containerRect.top}px`;
            } else {
                selection.style.top = `${startY + containerRect.top}px`;
            }
        });
        overlay.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
            isDragging = false;
            console.log("STOP DRAGG", isDragging)
            const selectionRect = selection.getBoundingClientRect();
            const overlayRect = overlay.getBoundingClientRect();
            const imgContainer = getContentContainer();

            if (imgContainer) {
                const naturalWidth = imgContainer.naturalWidth;
                const naturalHeight = imgContainer.naturalHeight;

                // Adjust selection coordinates to the overlay's position
                const offsetX = selectionRect.left - overlayRect.left; // X relative to overlay
                const offsetY = selectionRect.top - overlayRect.top; // Y relative to overlay

                // Convert coordinates to the image's natural dimensions
                const adjustedStartX = (offsetX / overlayRect.width) * naturalWidth;
                const adjustedStartY = (offsetY / overlayRect.height) * naturalHeight;
                const adjustedWidth = (selectionRect.width / overlayRect.width) * naturalWidth;
                const adjustedHeight = (selectionRect.height / overlayRect.height) * naturalHeight;

            // Store these coordinates and crop the image

            // let x = parseInt(selection.style.left) * dpr;
            // let y = parseInt(selection.style.top) * dpr;
            // let width = parseInt(selection.style.width) * dpr;
            // let height = parseInt(selection.style.height) * dpr;

            cropImage(dataUrl, adjustedStartX, adjustedStartY, adjustedWidth, adjustedHeight, function (croppedDataUrl) {
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
                    { action: "storeCroppedImage", dataUrl: croppedDataUrl, cropCoordinates: { x: adjustedStartX, y:adjustedStartY, width:adjustedWidth, height:adjustedHeight } },
                    function (response) {
                        if (response.status === "stored") {
                            console.log("Cropped image stored.", croppedDataUrl);
                        }
                    }
                );
                document.body.style.overflow = "";
                document.body.removeChild(overlay);
                document.body.removeChild(selection);
            });
            }
        });
    }
});

function cropImage(imageDataUrl :any, x :any, y :any, width :any, height :any, callback :any) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        // Get the 2D drawing context
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Check if the context is not null before using it
        if (ctx) {
            // Draw the cropped image
            ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);

            // Convert the cropped image to a Data URL and pass it to the callback
            const croppedDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            callback(croppedDataUrl);
        } else {
            console.error("Unable to get 2D context for the canvas.");
        }
    };
    img.src = imageDataUrl;
}

Can anyone suggest a solution to get the coordinates properly which can then be used on other files to get the exact crop in the same place.
